# Java VRPN Button server

Tags: java, vrpn

I'm trying to use `VRPN` to send stimulation data from my `Java` application to `OpenViBE`.

I can receive analog and button data in Java from the VRPN server included in OpenVibe,  using `java_vrpn and the included test classes (AnalogTest.java, ButtonTest.java)`

The examples included in `java_vrpn` only provide a possibility to send text messages though

How do I send button data from a Java VRPN server?

Please, *any* help would be really appreciated!
This stuff is driving me crazy, I can't even find if this is possible with the vrpn java lib!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a library to host vrpn servers in Java:

https://github.com/worosom/java_vrpn